# CMS encryption/decryption from openssl broken

Tags: c, encryption, openssl

So i navigated to the demos folder of openssl in

```
/usr/share/doc/libssl-doc/demos/cms
```

I compiled the test files there

```
gcc cms_enc.c -o enc -lssl -lcrypto
gcc cms_dec.c -o dec -lssl -lcrypto
```

Then i started both of them first ./enc then ./dec. Unfortunately the following error occured

```
140502142240416:error:0200B009:system library:fread:Bad file descriptor:bss_file.c:245:
140502142240416:error:20082002:BIO routines:FILE_READ:system lib:bss_file.c:246:
140502142240416:error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length:evp_enc.c:532:
```

So that means that the CMS implementation in openSSL is broken already? i wanted to use that functionality for my own c++ program but it failed so i wanted to try if even the examples work..

Comment: So `bss_file.c` is indeed the encrypted file that you are trying to decrypt? What key are you using to decrypt? Could you show us the input, output and command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
I compiled the test files there:

gcc cms_enc.c -o enc -lssl -lcrypto
gcc cms_dec.c -o dec -lssl -lcrypto
...

140502142240416:error:0200B009:system library:fread:Bad file descriptor:bss_file.c:245:
```

There's a typo in `cms_dec.c`. Scroll on down to line 50, and swap the `out` and the `NULL`. After the swap, it should look like:

```
/* Decrypt S/MIME message */
if (!CMS_decrypt(cms, rkey, rcert, NULL, out, 0))
    goto err;
```

Then recompile `cms_dec.c`. After the next run, there should be no error, and `decout.txt` should be as expected (the same as `encr.txt`).

Comment: No problem. Its been reported to OpenSSL: [Typo in .../demos/cms_dec.c](http://rt.openssl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=3218).