# bss_file.c and 0x20082002, 0x0200B015 errors when reading a file

Tags: c, linux, openssl

I  am writing  a code for an encryption/ decryption tool  with  ncurses window. I  can compile  the  code  successfully   , but  i  got  an error  while  i  am  running the  code.  When i  checked  the error  in  online ,  someone  saying that  the  openssl  encryption is  broken.  Anyway  i  am trying to  fix  this error, help  me  if anyone  have the  idea  about this  error...

> error:
>   140477540058784:error:0200B015:system library:fread:Is a
>   directory:bss_file.c:245:
>                                                                                                                                 140477540058784:error:20082002:BIO routines:FILE_READ:system
>   lib:bss_file.c:246:
>   140212739270304:error:0200B015:system library:fread:Is a
>   directory:bss_file.c:245:
>                                                                                                                                 140212739270304:error:20082002:BIO routines:FILE_READ:system
>   lib:bss_file.c:246:
>   140087821285024:error:0200B015:system library:fread:Is a
>   directory:bss_file.c:245:
>                                                                                                                                 140087821285024:error:20082002:BIO routines:FILE_READ:system
>   lib:bss_file.c:246:
>   139955942168224:error:0200B015:system library:fread:Is a
>   directory:bss_file.c:245:
>                                                                                                                                 139955942168224:error:20082002:BIO routines:FILE_READ:system
>   lib:bss_file.c:246:
>   139763690366624:error:0200B015:system library:fread:Is a
>   directory:bss_file.c:245:

Comment: Hi Bipin, could you provide your reference (this someone saying about ssl broken), possibly relevant code, and most advisely an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20937978/cms-encryption-decryption-from-openssl-broken

Comment: @BipinKunjumon: Does that link mean you had the same problem, and it is solved now?

Comment: i  had  follow  the  same  procedure that  mention  in  the  link,  but i  could not   resolve the issue...  thats  why  i  post  my  issue ....

Comment: It is OK to provide *additional information* via link, but a code which fails to execute constitutes **main information** about the problem, and Stack Overflow requires it to be **included into the question post itself**. In the linked question select parts, which are relevant for your question, and copy them into your question post via [edit].